# Local XML overrides to Magento extension's default configuration

Tags: magento, configuration

First off, excuse me if I make any mistakes regarding the Magento vernacular, this is my first project on the platform.

I'm working on an extension for Magento 1.7 that will be importing data from an FTP site (on the same server) nightly. Rather than hard-code the path to the FTP directory into my module I've added the following to app/code/local/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <default>
    <ftp_server_path>/home/ftpuser/</ftp_server_path>
  </default>
  ... other module configuration...
</config>
```

I'm able to access this stored value in my model using `Mage::getStoreConfig( 'ftp_server_path' )`.

Now what I'd like to do is override the `ftp_server_path` value on a per-environment basis (my local machine, staging, etc.). My first thought was app/etc/local.xml but I'm a) not sure if that's the appropriate location and b) unable to find a good example of environment-specific extension configuration being stored in app/etc/local.xml.

Any guidance you can provide in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just use the system.xml file to store this ftp path in the database in an editable field of the backend ?

Then you'll just need to change this on each backend to have local/dev/live version.

Create a system.xml file in your module's etc directory and put this in it :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<sections>
    <ftppath translate="label" module="yourmodule">
        <label>Manage </label>
        <tab>general</tab>
        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <general translate="label">
                <label>General</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <path translate="label">
                        <label>Path to FTP Server</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </path>
                </fields>
            </general>
        </groups>
    </ftppath>
</sections>
```

You can get this value by doing Mage::getStoreConfig('ftppath/general/path');

IF you need this section to be viewable only by admin of specific groups of users, create the acl in the adminhtml.xml file (still in the module's etc directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <ftppath translate="title" module="yourmodule">
                                    <title>Manage FTP</title>
                                    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                </ftppath>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

PS : I used to make something like that working in the app/etc/local.xml file but since 1.7 it doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: I was worried that making this editable through the backend would be complicated but between your answer and [Alan Storm's (outdated) article](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration) I was able to get it working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The info in the accepted SO answer, although a very good starting point, lacks a lot of what needs to be done to add a custom config section in the admin panel.

Even though it is a little outdated the article given by @SteveGrunwell ([here](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration)) in the accepted answer was instrumental for me to get it working. It is very detailed and to the point.

The outdated point seems to be that from version 1.4 and up, the ACL part is suppose to live in an adminhtml.xml file in the /etc/ folder of your module.

Another link that helped me on the [magento site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations)